# Correct use of NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, model-view-controller, nsnotificationcenter

I want to present a moderate volume of debug & logging messages (NSStrings) from deep within the model of my app to a panel in the UI, on the order of 2 or 3 lines every second. I anticipate needing this mostly during development, though I may leave the 'console' in for production. I am trying to keep to a clean MVC pattern since I don't know exactly how this app is going to turn out (it's a side project simulation engine, nothing commercial.)

I have implemented a method to write a log message to the view in my NSWindowController subclass by appending a line to an NSTextView. It works fine. However, I don't want my model - the source of the messages - to know anything about the WindowController, for obvious reasons. So:

- The NSNotificationCenter API seems to fit the bill. Does it? My alternatives would be a chain of log mechanisms that pass the message up the chain (Model->Document->WindowController->View), which is messy, or having the WC act as a delegate for the model's log method (making the WC adopt a simple protocol.) Again, that seems a bit scrappy. KVO doesn't seem to be a good fit for this because it's not some model state property that's changing. Have I missed anything?
- Should I expect significant performance hit by slamming NSNotificationCenter with multiple notifications each second?

Edit: I should say, it does work, but is it right?

Thanks

Comment: NSLog affects performance. Don't plan to log every several seconds. Only log as needed.

Comment: Hi @Moshe this isn't about NSLog though, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

two or three notifications per second is not a performance hit at all. If you feel using NSNotificationCenter, use it. For a logging mechanism, it may be unnecessary, however - doesn't a simple call to NSLog suffice?

Comment: Good to know. I specifically want the information in the UI; nothing to do with NSLog.

Comment: Well, updating the UI continuously is a bit more scary... but of course in this case it's encouraged not to link any core view controllers to the auxiliary logging mechanism anyway.

Comment: Yup. NSNotifications seems to be the most loosely-coupled way of doing this. It works anyway. Thanks